# How to list producers in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Just as Kafka Offset Monitor can show a list of active consumers of a topic, is there any tool or command line interface or anything that can list the name of producers publishing on a given topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view the MBeans over JMX, perhaps using jvisualvm (though you'll have to add the mbean browser plugin to it).  Once you connect to the broker, look in the following mbean path:

```
kafka.server -> Produce -> [contains your list of producers]
```

[image]

Comment: I have only one Attribute called "queu-size" in the given location. I'm using confluent-5.3.0 community version. How can I find a list of producers connected to a broker

Comment: Kafka 1.0.0 introduced a new restriction whereby these entries are only shown if a quota is implemented.  The solution is to add a quota that is ridiculously high which you will never exceed, and these client entries will instantly show up in JMX.  More info at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5402